# Как поменять массив и перезаписать

Tags: php

Есть массив. Туда записываются товары. Перед "+" id, после размер. Как из них делать два массива?

```
Array ( [0] => 25+43 [1] => 26+43 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример, используйте перебор элементов [FOR](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php), а далее [EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), максимально детально приведу пример, для понятия логики:

```
<?php
$array  = array('25+43','26+43');
$arrayID = array();
$arraySize = array();

if(!empty($array)){
  for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $exp = explode('+',$array[$i]);
    array_push($arrayID,$exp[0]);
    array_push($arraySize,$exp[1]);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$arr = ['25+43', '26+43'];
preg_match_all('~(?<id>\d+)\+(?<size>\d+)~', join(PHP_EOL, $arr), $a);

print_r($a['id']);
print_r($a['size']);
/*
Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 26 ) 
Array ( [0] => 43 [1] => 43 ) 
*/
```